# Manage Hyper-V VMs remotely without RDP

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, vnc

After searching a lot I couldn't find this anywhere so I'm asking here, I'm sorry if this was asked before.

Is there anyway to manage Hyper-V VMs remotely without having to connect to the Windows Server on which these VMs are running?

For example, lets say that I have a VM that doesn't have Internet connection, so I remotely connect to some kind of VNC that allows me to see that VM screen in particular.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

hyper-v management console, connect to it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how am I supposed to remotely connect to it.

Comment: you can enable hyper-v console on any computer, doesn't have to be on hyper-v server. Just like you can run server manager locally but connect to a remote server.